# SQLAlchemy: querying all objects with no direct relationship

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am new to ORM, so any comment are appreciated. Using the following code, I am trying to get all **Contacts** that are related to certain **Classification**.

```
Base = declarative_base()

contact_category_association_table = Table('contact_category_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('contact_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contacts.id')),
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contact_categories.id'))
)

class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contacts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    categories = relationship('ContactCategory', secondary=contact_category_association_table)


class ContactCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_categories'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    contacts = relationship('Contact', secondary=contact_category_association_table)
    classification_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('contact_classification.id'))
    classification = relationship('ContactClassification', back_populates='categories')


class ContactClassification(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_classification'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    categories = relationship('ContactCategory', back_populates='classification')
```

Using the following SQL I managed to get a result close to my need. However, I could not translate that using sqlalchemy ORM.

```
select * from contacts c
join contact_categories cc,  contact_category_association cca, contact_classification ccl
where c.id = cca.contact_id and cc.id = cca.category_id and ccl.id = cc.classification_id;
```

The result I am seeking is a dict object. The key will be the id or name of the classification. The value will be a list of contacts.

### **Update:**

To elaborate more. Each contact is categorized by their profession (ContactCategory). The relation between contact and category is many-to-many. Categories are being classified (or group) into classes. Each category can belong to 1 class (one-to-many). The following are an example data:

```
Contacts
1|Alpha
2|Bear
3|Cel
4|Deer
5|Elk

ContactCategory
1|Builder|2
2|Carpenter|2
3|Metal Works|2
4|Networking & Cabling|1
5|Gypsum|2

ContactClassification
1|Electronics
2|Building & Decor
3|Plumping & Piping

contact_category_association
1|1
1|2
2|2
3|4
4|2
4|5
5|5
```

Using ORM, I want to get the following result it possible (as python dict object):

```
result = {
'Electronics': [<Cel>],
'Building & Decor': [<Alpha>, <Bear>, <Deer>, <Elk>],
'Plumping & Piping': []
}
```

Where the key is the class name and the value is a list of contacts that belong to each class (through the category).

I am sorry if the table names are confusing. I am in refactoring process of a side-project and got no time to rename the tables yet.

You help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you're trying to achieve. Include a concrete sample of the result you're after. The sample query you've displayed does not reflect "I am trying to get all Contacts that **are related to certain** Classification."

Comment: I've updated the question and provided an example of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you had in mind since empty results will not be included, but in general you could query `contact_classification.name, contacts.*` tuples and group in Python:

```
from collections import defaultdict

query = session.query(ContactClassification.name, Contact).\
    join('categories', 'contacts')

result = defaultdict(list)

for klass, contact in query:
    result[klass].append(contact)
```